# How to get {ID} in url "controller/action/id" in a post action?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In the cshtml file, I have the following javascript in `Home/Details/4`. 4 is the ID.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#checkbox").click(function () {
            $.post(
                "Home/Toggle", 
                { checkbox: $("#checkbox").val() }, 
                function (data) {

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The following is the action code in the controller.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Toggle(bool checkbox)
    {
        ...... // How to get ID?
        var x = db.XXXX.Find(id);
```

How to get the ID? From some routing data, or Url, or let the front jQuery posting pass it?

**Is it possible to get the ID from the action method without passing from the front html page?**

Comment: i think this is what you want if need some more help then comment...

Comment: It's unclear what the bool does in your action? The route you use `/Controller/Action/Id`, should it be `/Controller/Action/Bool/Id`? I mean you want to pass both values?

Comment: -1. Explain a bit more about your situation. Do you have and `Id` in your html. Why you don't want to pass it with jquery?

Answer (score 4):

First of all slash before the controller name in the url is missing:

```
"/Home/Toggle"
```

Next mistake is checkbox value can not be check by using val() method but it can be checked using:

```
$("#checkbox").is(':checked')
```

Next you have to append id after the url as it mapped like "controller/action/{id}" in RouteConfig.cs file in RegisterRoutes method.

So your final correct url will be:

```
"/Home/Toggle/{id}"  //in your case: "/Home/Toggle/4"
```

In Action method "id" parameter is also missing. Corrected Action method is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public void Toggle(bool checkbox, int id)
    {

    }
```

And your complete and corrected Jquery code is:

```
$.post("/Home/Toggle/4", { checkbox: $("#checkbox").is(':checked') }, function (data) {

            });
```

Answer (score 2):

If your `url` is this `Home/Details/4` then you can get `'id'` as :-

```
 public ActionResult Toggle(bool checkbox, int? id) //<----get 'id' this way
 {}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your script, assign the id

```
var id = '@Model.ID';
```

then include it when posting back

```
$.post("Home/Toggle", { checkbox: $("#checkbox").val(), ID: id }, function (data) { ...
```

and adjust your post method to

```
public ActionResult Toggle(int ID, bool checkbox)
{
  ....
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the ID from the action method without passing from the front html page?

Comment: Not unless you application is psychic

Comment: At low http protocol level, the id may be able to be found in the `refer`.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9, If the client never sends `id`, how can the server read it?

Answer (score 2):

It all depends what your html looks like? You probably want to save your id as a hidden or `data-some-name` on to a html element.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.NameId)
```

or

```
<div class="some-class" data-id="@Model.NameId"></div>
```

Your action should take both parameters you want to pass in (or view model for that matter).

```
public ActionResult Toggle(bool checkbox, int id)
    {
```

Your post should look like this. Note this is when using the hidden input "store" method.

```
$.post("Home/Toggle", { checkbox: $("#checkbox").val(), id: $('.NameId').val() }, function (data) {

});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to change going to id in your ajax post function and add id to Toggle function or add new toggle function with id as parameter.
If you want to keep going value in post function you need to add a new routing

Comment: if you mean how pass id=4 you should in your post function add id:4 after checkbox